# How to append the second column data below the value of first column data?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:

df

```
Name   Sequence
abc    ghijklmkhf
bhf    uyhbnfkkkkkk
dmf    hjjfkkd
```

I want to append the second column data to the below of the first column data in specific format as follows:

```
Name   Sequence       Merged
abc    ghijklmkhf     >abc
                      ghijklmkhf
bhf    uyhbnfkkkkkk   >bhf
                      uyhbnfkkkkkk
dmf    hjjfkkd        >dmf
                      hjjfkkd
```

I tried `df['Name'] = '>' + df['Name'].astype(str)` to get the name in the format with `>` symbol. How do I append the second column data below the value of first column data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use vectorial concatenation:

```
df['Merged'] = '>'+df['Name']+'\n'+df['Sequence']
```

output:

```
  Name      Sequence              Merged
0  abc    ghijklmkhf    >abc\nghijklmkhf
1  bhf  uyhbnfkkkkkk  >bhf\nuyhbnfkkkkkk
2  dmf       hjjfkkd       >dmf\nhjjfkkd
```

Checking that there are two lines:

```
print(df.loc[0, 'Merged'])

>abc
ghijklmkhf
```

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to the mozway's solution, if you want to see the dataframe exactly with the format you mentioned, use the following:

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML

df["Merged"] = ">"+df["Name"]+"\n"+df["Sequence"]

def pretty_print(df):
    return display(HTML(df.to_html().replace("\\n","<br>")))

pretty_print(df)
```